# how change the the order of the text in Notepad++, using Regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++

My question is very simple, I just need to change this text:

```
} else if (elemento.equalsIgnoreCase("CS"))...
} else if (elemento.equalsIgnoreCase("RP"))...
} else if (elemento.equalsIgnoreCase("BD"))...
```

...to this:

```
} else if ("CS".equalsIgnoreCase(elemento))...
} else if ("RP".equalsIgnoreCase(elemento))...
} else if ("BD".equalsIgnoreCase(elemento))...
```

In order to do this, I am using the find/replace from Notepad (REGEX mode), but anyway I can't do it.

Comment: Can you do this with a macro?

Comment: Why the downvotes? It is a question valid for the SO rules.

Comment: I tryed use a macro, but the string between quotes is variable and I can´t created a macro that works for all cases. For instance, sometimes is just "CD" and others "AR ST DF".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
(elemento)(\.)(equalsIgnoreCase\()("[A-Z]*")(\))
```

and on replace field

```
\4.\3\1\5
```

Comment: Works fine! Thanks
Muchas gracias Jorge!

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Search` > `Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   (elemento)(\.equalsIgnoreCase\()("[A-Z]+")
   ```
2. Replace with:

   ```
   $3$2$1
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression"
4. Then press "Replace All"

You can test it at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/qT6jI1).